# Рандом с процентной вероятностью С++

Tags: c++

Добрый день, уважаемые знатоки. Недавно начал изучать самостоятельно язык С++. Вот прошел оператор условий, выбора и цикл. Захотелось придумать простенькую программку в качестве упражнения. В компьютерных играх есть такое понятие, как заточка(улучшение) вещей. Я решил написать программу, с помощью которой можно попытать удачу улучшить(заточить) предмет. Каждое успешное улучшение нумеруется как +1, +2 и т.д. Идея такая: вероятность заточки на +1 50%, на +2 47, на +3 44% и тд. Везде по 3% снимается. Максимальная заточка +12. Но код мой не работает.Компилируется, запускается, но результат не тот.Я его приведу ниже:
Пы.Сы. Не серчайте на ошибки и, скорее всего, ложный ход мысли. Я был только на трех занятиях и еще мало что усвоил.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int g;
    float ver=53;
    float k=3;
    for(int j=0;j<12;j++)
    {
        ver=ver-k;
        cin>>g://эта переменная ничего не делает, я хотел ее считывать просто, чтобы цикл не сам шел до конца, а я каждый новый круг что-то нажимал. Если вы знаете, как заставить компилятор реагировать на простое нажатие Ентера, подскажите пожалуйста.
         if ((rand()%100) < ver)
         {
        cout<<"Vi zatocchili shmotku na +"<<j<<endl;
         }
    else  if ((rand()%100) > ver)
    {
        cout<<"Uroven zatochki upal do 0";
        break;// Это я поставил для остановки цикла, если улучшение не прошло

    }

    }

    _getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: http://pastebin.ru/GCPsEmwA

Comment: Да где вы все берете эти книжки с conio.h???

Comment: >Да где вы все берете эти книжки с conio.h???

да что там книжки, у нас до сих пор в некоторых институтах (!!!) Turbo Pascal преподают)

Comment: conio я находил в какой-то книжке. Спасибо большое, за помощь. Подскажите пожалуйста, что значит эта строчка
getline(std::cin, g);

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Answer (score 1):

`if ((rand()%100) < ver)` - нормальная идея. Хотя, строго говоря, вероятность будет чуть-чуть отличаться от ver%. Т.к. rand() может выдавать значения, например, от 0 до 32767 и вероятность получить 0 - 328/32768, а получить 99 - только 327/32768.

И не пишите `else  if ((rand()%100) > ver)` - будет сравнение уже с новым случайным числом, скорее всего Вам нужен просто else.